# Unity gradle build failed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gradle, build, apk

I can't build another APK in Unity. Always the same error.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
]
stdout[
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\m-pro\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1 in C:\Users\m-pro\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1 not accepted.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

My settings and things I've tried:

- JDK version 1.8
- SDK build tool version 25
- I tried to copy "-dontwarn com.google.vr.ndk.base.DaydreamApi" into a proguard file (saw this type of a solution somewhere)
- Swap from gradle build to internal build (as internal build a different error comes up)
- Reinstall all and restart my computer :D

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with my Unity builds after the build tools got an update, so you may just have to update them too.

as it says in the error message you need to accept the TOS using android studio

`You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.`

- [Install Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) on your PC (if you havn't already)
- run its SDK manager (configure > SDK manager > SDK tools)
- If Android SDK build-tools says "Not installed", click the checkbox right next to it to install it.
- if It says "Update available" click the checkbox with the "-" next to it so it shows a "✓"
- hit apply, and accept the agreement.

That is what fixed it for me, hope this also works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your help <3
Buuut after that another error comes up :(

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/245591632852811776/438402581526609932/Capture.PNG?width=895&height=441

played here a bit around 

not sure if I did it right

Comment: hmmm, i have never encountered that issue myself. All i can really say on that matter is to check if your path is correct (copy the path you set at JAVA_HOME into your explorer, and see if it opens the folder.) It may just be mismatch in the version name.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, I ran into this after upgrading from Unity 2020.3.24f1 to Unity 2020.3.38f1
What fixed it for me was getting the JDK and SDK paths from the Unity/Preferences/external tools, then in a terminal window:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<the JDK path Unity is using>
<SDK path Unity is using>/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

for me this was:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.38f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.38f1//PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

This will then prompt to accept several licenses which appear under

```
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.38f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/licenses
```

Without the export JAVA_HOME to Unity's version, the sdkmanager --licenses would fail with a Java error.

After I figured this out on my own, I happened to notice the solution in Unity forums as well here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/gradle-build-faled.999773/